# Auto restart on Samsung Galaxy Grand Quattro

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I've got a [Samsung Galaxy Grand Quattro](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_win_i8550-5392.php).
When I was using it suddenly switched off after showing a blue screen. And when I tried to switch it ON. It was ON for sometime, but switched off again and kept doing that till the battery drained out. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Text say "Samsung Galaxy Grand Quattro", tag say "Samsung Galaxy S2"...

Comment: What phone do you actually have? Is it rooted? What firware is it running?